# Displaytag is exporting CSV into a .xls file

Tags: excel, displaytag

I export an Excel document with DisplayTag.  It saves as a .xls file to my Desktop.  When I open it with Excel, this error displays:

"The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension.  Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file."

If I click "Yes", it displays just fine in Excel.  If I open this with Textpad, I see that it's a binary file, but it appears to just be "." delimited strings.

Any ideas what I might have done wrong, or how next to debug this?

*edit:*:

If I change the extension to .txt, it's not a binary file; it's simply a list of delimited strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default export class for Excel was set to the CSV class, but giving it the .xls extension.  Changing displaytag.properties was the key here, something like:

```
export.types=csv excel xml rtf pdf 
export.excel=true
export.xml=true
export.csv=true
export.rtf=false
export.pdf=false
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.DefaultHssfExportView
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
export.rtf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultRtfExportView
export.excel.filename=data.xls
export.pdf.filename=data.pdf
export.xml.filename=data.xml
export.csv.filename=data.csv
export.rtf.filename=data.rtf
```

Comment: Hi, I try this solution on 1.1 version and don´t work for me, my file don´t chanve from csv to excel.

Comment: Doesn't work in 1.2, just as the previous commenter wrote also. I'm still getting a CSV file written into XLS. I created a new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527793/displaytag-outputs-csv-file-even-though-excel-format-is-specified-in-displaytag

Answer (score 3):

Are you on Excel 2007?  Seems to be a [known](http://www.itexperience.net/2008/03/17/excel-2007-error-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension/) issue:

> In some cases after upgrading to Excel
>   2007, you may get the following error:
>   The file you are trying to open .xlsx
>   is in a different format than
>   specified by the file extension.
>   verify the file is not corrupted and
>   is from trusted source before opening
>   the file. Do you want to open the file
>   now?

This errors particularly occurs when you’re trying to open an XLS file (Excel 2000-2003) with Excel 2007. In most cases, the problem can be solved by defining MIME types and associating them with extensions.

...

However, if you don’t want to look for a solution, but just want to solve the problem, insert this key in your registry to suppress the notification:

**[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security] “ExtensionHardening”=dword:00000000**

You can accomplish the above by doing the following:

1. Open your Registry (Start -> Run ->
   regedit.exe)
2. Navigate to
   **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\12.0\EXCEL\SECURITY**
3. Right click in the right window and
       choose **New** -> **DWORD**
4. Type “*ExtensionHardening*” as the
   name (without the quotes)
5. Verify that the data has the value
   “**0**″

Comment: Thank you!  

That page seems to be blocked at my company's firewall, but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Rotating back, nope, that wasn't it.  :-/

Comment: Hmm..  added some more details from the thread if you can't access from the office..

Comment: Gave that a shot, but no luck; it really seems to just be a delimited text file that's being sent to the browser, which Excel 2007 (half) chokes on.

Comment: When you ouput to Excel, isn't DisplayTag just creating a CSV file?  (CSV's usually default to Excel).  Should you be saving this with a .csv extension?

Comment: CSV is a separate option, which also seems to produce CSV.  Excel is exporting a CSV... with an XLS extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below lines in your properties file:

```
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.DefaultHssfExportView
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
```

But this outputs the current page record only and not the complete list.