# Displaytag Export Excel not exporting all rows

Tags: excel, jsp, export, displaytag

I want to export the table data into Excel using Displaytag.

Initially it's exporting all the data to Excel, however by default displaytag is using CSV format to export into Excel.

This solution fixed that problem [Displaytag is exporting CSV into a .xls file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366570/displaytag-is-exporting-csv-into-a-xls-file)

However, now new generated excel sheet is having only the selected page data rather than entire table/list. It's exporting 2nd page data is I am in 2nd page and so on.

But I want to export all pages data.

my complete displaytag.properties

```
export.types=csv excel xml rtf pdf  
export.excel=true
export.xml=true 
export.csv=true
export.rtf=false
export.pdf=false
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.DefaultHssfExportView
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
export.rtf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultRtfExportView
```

in Jsp for the table

```
<displaytag:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="test.csv" />
<displaytag:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="test.xls" />
<displaytag:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="test.xml" />
```

Btw, other export formats (csv,xml) are generating complete data except for excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be bug and known issue in Displaytag
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/DISPL-361

I found a workaround, might be useful for others!

```
if(this.request.getParameter(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_EXPORTING) != null)){
  return complete List;
}else {
  return based on user inputs
}
```

Comment: where should I write this code? please provide some explanations

Answer (score 1):

The export amount controlled by below property configuration

```
export.amount=page  //only current page will be exported
export.amount=list //whole list will be exported
```

And Also try

```
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.ExcelHssfView
```

[ExcelHssfView](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag-export-poi/apidocs/org/displaytag/export/excel/ExcelHssfView.html)

instead of

```
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.DefaultHssfExportView
```

or don't add this property (export.excel.class) in the .property file

Comment: FYI, this requires DisplayTag *2.0.2* which is "unofficial" (officially DisplayTag stops at 1.2). You'll need to download the unofficial, non-supported file *displaytag-2.0.2jar.* The last version 1.2 does not have `ExcelHssfView`.