# Does Displaytag's ExcelView even work? Getting Non-Excel output of plain strings

Tags: jsp, displaytag

According to the [Displaytag 1.2 documentation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/export.html), `ExportView` is provided to output Excel files.

But actually, the source code shows that the entire Excel Model structure is just a plain data  bean of strings. The result of using `ExcelView` to output an XLS is the following plain-text output (not a valid XLS),

```
"Agreement Category"    "Approving Official"    "Second Level Approving Official"   
"Regular"   "John Smith"    "Test"
```

Indeed, the `ExcelView` Model package is just a String-based set of classes, like a POJO bean,

```
org.displaytag.model.Column
org.displaytag.model.HeaderCell
...
```

I understand that Displaytag also has a completely different renderer, `org.displaytag.export.excel.DefaultHssfExportView` , which uses HSSF to write XLS files. That renderer **does** produce a valid Excel file. (It's in the JAR *displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar*.)

So what's the purpose of `ExcelView`, then? Is it a final renderer, or just an interface renderer of some kind? Does it assume more implementation? Why call it `ExcelView` if it doesn't actually output Excel, just a String list? Are we supposed to use `DefaultHssfExportView` for all Excel exports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DisplayTag is a bad and poorly supported library, but here's what I've been able to find:

1. What it misleadingly calls `org.displaytag.export.ExcelView` is just a quote-enclosed String Renderer (they [call](http://www.displaytag.org/10/export.html) it "ascii format, tab separated" )
   At least one user [thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061416/displaytag-export-excel-not-exporting-all-rows) it was CSV, but it's not, because there are no commas (CSV requires commas -- here it's just spaces and quotes: "test" "test2" etc.).
2. To actually output a real Excel file you need:

a)
`export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.DefaultHssfExportView` in *displaytag.properties*

b)
with: **displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar** (this contains the `DefaultHssfExportView`),

c) with: **poi-3.2-FINAL.jar**  This is very important. You [can't use a higher POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877445/problem-with-using-displaytag-tiles-to-export-excel/23538224#23538224) version with `DefaultHssfExportView`.

This outputs a good Excel file, but there's one remaining problem: the current **Page** only (not the full List). Various ideas have been proposed to get the full List, such as [using a different renderer called `org.displaytag.export.excel.ExcelHssfView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24860472/1005607). This other renderer is also available in *display-export-poi-1.2.jar* but I get a ClassDefNotFound on it for some reason, and it can't be used. Only the `DefaultHssfExportView` renderer is found, instantiated, and works.

So for now I get a valid Excel file back, but with a Page-only set rather than the full set. There is no solution for the full set in the rendered XLS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the full binary Excel export with:

displaytag 1.2 and displaytag-export-poi 1.2

e.g. in `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation 'displaytag:displaytag:1.2'
    implementation 'displaytag:displaytag-export-poi:1.2'
```

and adding the following to `displaytag.properties`:

```
export.excel.class=org.displaytag.export.excel.ExcelHssfView
```